# Non-recursive js->clj in ClojureScript

Tags: clojurescript

I have a JavaScript array of JavaScript objects.  I'd like to turn it into a vector of JavaScript objects.  However, js->clj is recursive, such that the JavaScript objects themselves would be turned into CLJS maps.

How can I turn a JavaScript array into a CLJS vector without touching the elements inside the array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(vec the-array)` or `(into [] the-array)` will both turn the array into a vector and not touch the objects at all.

Comment: Iff you know that the JavaScript array won't be modified, favor `vec` as it is faster.

Comment: Is there a similar way to shallowly convert objects to hash-maps?